# websocket connection working on mac not on windows

Tags: python, windows, macos, sockets, websocket

I'm trying to control a webpage with a desktop application. The architecture is:

App -> socket->websocket->(javascript+html)

So, a message originates in the app (client.py) then sends it to a socket server (combined.py) that relays it to the webpage (scriptsp.js and to test.html)

I have stripped the code to a minimum of what I am doing. To replicate the problem you can open **3 terminal windows** (or Powershell/cmd) and a web browser,

1. Start `combined.py` to get a socket server on *terminal 1*.
2. Then start a webserver where `test.html` is (e.g. `python -m http.server 9090`) on *terminal 2*.
3. load `http://localhost:9090/test.html` in the web browser
4. start `client.py` on *terminal 3*
5. Type the IP from `combined.py` in *terminal 1*
6. Type a message  in *terminal 3*

If you are on mac, Terminal 1 will show the message, and the webpage will show an alert (and console log) with the message you typed in terminal 3. If you are in Windows, Terminal 1 will show the message, but the webpage won't do anything.

Any ideas? I have disabled the firewall on windows, and tried enabling websockets in the Internet Service. Anybody else find the same problem?

See code below:

`combined.py`

```
# import socket library
import socket
# import threading library
import threading
# import websocket library
import websockets

import asyncio



# Choose a port that is free
PORT = 5555

# An IPv4 address is obtained
# for the server.
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

# Address is stored as a tuple
ADDRESS = (SERVER, PORT)

# the format in which encoding
# and decoding will occur
FORMAT = "utf-8"

# Lists that will contains
# all the clients connected to
# the server and their names.
clients, names = [], []
# Create a new socket for
# the server
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                    socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# bind the address of the
# server to the socket
server.bind(ADDRESS)

# function to start the connection
async def startListening(websocket, path):
    print("server is working on " + SERVER)
    # listening for connections
    server.listen()
    while True:
        # accept connections and returns
        # a new connection to the client
        # and the address bound to it
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        clients.append(conn)
        print(f"Connection to {addr} successful!".encode(FORMAT))
        # broadcast message
        conn.send(f"Connection to {addr} successful!".encode(FORMAT))
        # Start the handling thread
        thread = threading.Thread(target=async_handle,
                                args=(conn, addr, websocket))
        thread.start()
        # no. of clients connected
        # to the server
        print(f"active connections {threading.active_count()-1}")

# method to handle the
# incoming messages
def async_handle(conn, addr, websocket):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(handle(conn, addr, websocket))
        loop.close()


async def handle(conn, addr, websocket):
    print(f"new connection {addr}")
    connected = True
    while connected:
        message = conn.recv(1024).decode(FORMAT)
        print(message)
        try:
            conn.send(f"{message} - was received".encode(FORMAT))
            await websocket.send(message)
        except:
            print("EXCEPTION SENDING MESSAGE.",sys.exc_info()[0])
    # close the connection
    conn.close()


start_server = websockets.serve(startListening, "localhost", 8000)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

`client.py`

```
# import all the required modules
import socket
import threading
import sys

# Control class
class Control:

    client = None
    PORT = 5555
    SERVER = ""
    FORMAT = "utf-8"

    # constructor method
    def __init__(self):
        #read ip and connect
        self.connectToServer(input("IP?:"))
        snd = threading.Thread(target=self.sendMessage)
        snd.start()


    def connectToServer(self, serverIP):
        Control.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        Control.SERVER = serverIP
        Control.ADDRESS = (Control.SERVER, Control.PORT)
        Control.client.connect(Control.ADDRESS)

        # the thread to receive messages
        rcv = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)
        rcv.start()

    # function to receive messages
    def receive(self):
        while True:
            try:
                message = Control.client.recv(1024).decode(Control.FORMAT)
                print("MESSAGE:",message)
            except:
                # an error will be printed on the command line or console if there's an error
                print("ERROR RECEIVING",sys.exc_info()[0])
                Control.client.close()
                break

    # function to send messages
    def sendMessage(self):
        while True:
            message = input("Message?:")
            try:
                Control.client.send(message.encode(Control.FORMAT))
            except:
                print("ERROR SENDING",sys.exc_info()[0])
                break


# create a Control class object
g = Control()
```

`scriptsp.js`

```
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000");

socket.addEventListener("open", function (event) {
  socket.send("Connection Established to web");
  alert("Connection Established");
});

socket.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
  const msg = event.data;
  alert(msg)
  console.log(`Received ${msg}`);
});

socket.addEventListener("error",function (event){
    alert("ERROR OCCURRED!");
    console.log(event);
})

socket.addEventListener("close", function (event) {
  alert("Connection Closed");
});

const contactServer = () => {
  socket.send("Initialize");
};
```

`test.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <title>Test WebSocket</title>
        <script src="scriptsp.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>You will see your alerts pop up</p>
    </body>
</html>
```